# Deserializing Xml which has the same element name but different attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have some XML which looks like this:

```
<Stat Type="first_name">[Value]</Stat>
<Stat Type="last_name">[Value]</Stat>
<Stat Type="known_name">[Value]</Stat>
```

I want to deserialize this to an object. As there is one element name called "Stat" it's making it difficult to get something like:

```
[XmlAttribute("first_name")]
public string FirstName{get;set;}

[XmlAttribute("last_name")]
public string LastName{get;set;}

[XmlAttribute("known_name")]
public string KnownName{get;set;}
```

Is there a way of getting the XML above into an object like:

```
public string FirstName{get;set;}
public string LastName{get;set;}
public string KnownName{get;set;}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using an extension. Not ideal. I get the list of stats:

```
[XmlElement("Stat")]
public List<Stat> Stats { get; set;}
```

Then I have separate properties like:

```
public string FirstName
{
   get { return Stats.GetStat("first_name"); }
}
```

The GetStat extension method  on the Stats property then gets the relevant key. Unfortunately, this way, it will run through that list for each property I want to get.

```
public static string GetStat(this List<Stat> stats, string key)
{
  var val = stats.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Type == key);

  if (val != null)
    return val.Value ?? String.Empty;
  return String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use serialization I think you will need an intermediate object.  So, deserialize into something like this:

```
public class Stat
{
    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then write some code to flatten into the shape you want.

Comment: I had this in the code already. But I need to be able put the data from this into my object.

Answer (score 0):

you'll probably have to parse the XML yourself with XPath or something. Mines a bit rusty, but its something like:

```
var stat = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.GetSingleNode("stat[@type='first_name']");
var value = stat.InnerText;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd need to try and do this within the serializer rather than using XPath.