# POST method with multiple variables of same name

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Very new to asp.net and web services so forgive me. I have a POST method that posts a sales order to my webpage. The problem I am running into is that, the sales order can sometimes have a variable called "Detail" associated with it. This variable can occur 1...n times depending on the sales order. This variable is always called "Detail" and I have no control of changing it. So, I guess my question is, how can I create a variable called Detail for my SalesOrder class that can be repeated multiple times and displayed not just the first, but all.

Attempted: Looping through request.querystrings, arrays of the struct Detail, declaring Detail as a class and using the new declaration.

I am using.net framework 4.5

Here is my salesorder model:

```
public struct shipTo
{

public string id;
public string Line1;
public int PostalCode;
public string City;
public string State;
public string CountryCode;

public void getValues(string l, string c, string s, int pc, string cc, string id)
{
    Line1 = l;
    PostalCode = pc;
    City = c;
    State = s;
    CountryCode = cc;

}
}

public struct Detail
{

public string LineNumber { get; set; }
public string GradeItem { get; set; }
public string Quantity { get; set; }
public string UOM { get; set; }
public string RequestDate { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }

}

namespace USS_EDIv2.Models
{
public class Order
{

        public Int64 SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }
        public Int64 PurchaseOrderNumber { get; set; }
        public Int64 BranchPlant { get; set; }
        public shipTo ShipTo;
        public Int64 Quantity { get; set; }
        public string UOM { get; set; }   
        public Detail Detail;


}


}
```

and the xml request that is being POSTed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wir6k.jpg

and the response:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcVmN.jpg

If the controller is necessary to view as well please let me know of any information i have excluded and I will post. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show code as code, not as images. There's no way to copy and paste that XML to reproduce the problem. For the problem, as indicated in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686740/deserializing-xml-which-has-the-same-element-name-but-different-attributes) the solution is just to make your "Detail" property have the type `List<Detail>`.

Comment: Any particular reason why you made these as `structs`?

Comment: None in particular. As they, ShipTo and Detail, contained their own information I set them up as structs to avoid conflicting variable names and cleanliness.

Answer (score 0):

I gather that the XML is posted as part of the HTTP body.  That means you should use a content-type other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, such as text/html.  If that is the case, then you won't be able to retrieve any of the values from `Request.Form[]` because that is for HTML form posts in a certain format.

Instead, you need to get ahold of the entire XML blob as a string and parse it yourself.  The controller declaration should look something like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyAction([FromBody]string XmlAsString)
{
    var xml = ParseXml(XmlAsString);
    DoSomethingWithObject(xml);
}
```

Note the use of the [FromBodyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) which indicates that the variable should be populated with the entire form body.

Once you have the XML as a string, you can parse it any number of ways.

1. Use a schema definition to define a series of classes that match the schema, then deserialize using [XmlSerializer.Deserialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Pull out the data you need using [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. Use [Linq-to-Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693116.aspx).

Each of these is rather involved, but I will show you a quick example using LINQ.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyAction([FromBody]string XmlAsString)
{
    XElement root = XElement.Parse(XmlAsString);
    IEnumerable detailList = from seg in root.Descendants("Detail")
                             select (string)seg;
    DoSomethingWithDetails(detailList);
}
```